# Should a sync provider be an Android library or application?

Tags: android

Regarding Android >= 2.0.1.

This speaks for Application type of project:

- The provided sample code makes it an
  application.
- Easy testing in dev tools.

This speaks for Library type of project:

- From another application wanting to
  trigger a sync, I would like to
  include it as a library dependency.

What other benefits/drawbacks can you see with either type of project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it work as a part of your Application first and (if necessary) refactor into a library later.

Comment: Makes sense, since testing is impossible/hard when the project is defined as a library. I value testability more than other features, so I'll make mine an application project.